# Sql Column had no values

Tags: sql, alter-table

I have a sql table that I am trying to add a column from another table to. Only when I execute the alter table query it does not pull the values out of the table to match the column where I am trying to make the connection.

For example I have column A from table 1 and column A from table 2, they are supposed to coincide. ColumnATable1 being an identification number and ColumnATable2 being the description.

I tried this but got an error...

```
alter table dbo.CommittedTbl
add V_VendorName nvarchar(200)
where v_venkey = v_vendorno
```

It tells me that I have incorrect syntax... Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do it in two statements. Remove the where clause from the alter table statement and have a look at how you can use `update` to move the data from one table to another.

Comment: You'd get much more helpful answers if you were to provide us with your extant structure.

Comment: Why are you duplicating an nvarchar(200) value and storing it in both tables? This is wasteful to store redundantly and, since it's a name it's likely to change, which means you will have to update in more than one place. Typically surrogate keys are used to make this linkage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alter table dbo.CommittedTbl
add V_VendorName nvarchar(200);

go

update c
set c.V_VendorName = a.V_VendorName
from CommittedTbl c
join TableA a
on c.v_venkey = a.v_vendorno;

go
```

I'm just guessing at your structure here.

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table 2 add column A <some_type>;
update table2 set column A = (select column_A from table2 where v_venkey = v_vendorno);
```

Your names for tables and columns are a bit confusing but I think that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no WHERE clause for an ALTER TABLE statement.  You will need to add the column (your first two lines), and then insert rows based upon a relationship you define between the two tables.

ALTER TABLE syntax:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are several languages within SQL:

DDL: Data Definition Language - this defines the schema (the structure of tables, columns, data types) - adding a column to a table affects the table definitions and all rows will have that new column (not just some rows according to a criteria)

DML: Data Manipulation Language - this affects data within a table, and inserting, updating or other changes fall into this and you can update some data according to criteria (and this is where a `WHERE` clause would come in)

`ALTER` is a DDL statement, while `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are DML statements.

The two cannot really be mixed as you are doing.

You should `ALTER` your table to add the column, then `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the column to include appropriate data.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you want a JOIN query instead? If you want to join two tables or parts of two tables you should use JOIN.

have a look at this for a start if you need to know more [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

hope that helps!